# Issue with Application Packaging in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, packaging

I have an app I built, deployed and is being tested with Google Developer Tester Option. My app(s) i have been developing has a wierd issue I can not put my finger on.

The App is a simple Note Taking App. So there is not a lot of code. I done my main activity only has about 60 lines of code. Everything else is composed of classes.

When I test my app on my cellphone. There is a time delay of 5 seconds that a white screen shows while launching. Then it goes to the app.

I would usually put a splash screen. And its seamless in loading. Without the splash screen with normal code it shows the white screen for 5 seconds.

My question is, am I doing something or wrong or is this something with the transition of `.apk` to `.aab` when packaging?

I have read articles of people saying its a bug withing Android itself. I have no warnings or errors within the app.

This has me puzzled and any advice would be helpful.

Here is a screenshot of the start up process.

[image]

Then this happens for 5 seconds then the main app shows

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can set theme https://medium.com/android-news/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52

Comment: @VidyeshChuri for this app i am not adding a splash screen. With a splash screen it works fine. But for a Note taking app splash screen is not necessary

Comment: @camp-nerd Can you hide images to links on imgur etc. from question and attach code of MainActivity, Application and build.gradle (App module). You tried launching app on other real devices and emulators without debug mode + obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some test coding I finally solved the issue. To have the White Screen not appear you can create a splash screen or just a theme.

`Theme` should be set as follows

```
<style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your `SplashScreen.kt` you can add the following

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed({
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }, 2000)
```

Then in your `Manifest` you need add the following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">

    </activity>
```

This cuts the launch time with the Splash Screen to whatever your delay is set at.

Comment: i have tested this on several 4 phones and 3 tablets it worked just like it was supposed too

Answer (score 0):

Your application can't launch instantly, the time it takes to launch an application depends on several hardware factors. So the launch time is different from one smartphone to another

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time